I would like to change the quota for sending requests per minute.(message-rate-exceeded)
I would like to change the quota for sending requests per minute.(message-rate-exceeded)
enter image description here
I am using fcm message api with firebase admin sdk.
I want to change from 600k to 1000k
Is it possible to change to administrator?
Is there no solution other than a resending policy with exponential backoff?

This is not a value that you can change/increase yourself.
If you consistently need to send more than 600,000 messages per second, you can reach out to Firebase support to request a quota increase. Before doing so, please study the documentation on sending FCM messages at scale carefully, as failing to heed the guidance in there is a common cause for requests being rejected.

Thank you for answer. How do I get Firebase support?

https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+get+Firebase+support%3F
